# Is there cross browser word-wrap: overflow-wrap solution?

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve the following effect:

[image]

But it seems like the only way to do this is with `word-wrap: overflow-wrap` which isn't widely supported.

So instead the only solution I seem to have is to use: `word-break: break-all` which will produce the following results:

[image]

**NOTICE:** how the from is broken in the second picture?  What styles do I need to use to get the results from the first image?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jennifergoncalves/k4yn9ucf/

Answer (score 4):

`word-wrap` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)) is a legacy name for `overflow-wrap`. `word-wrap` is required for IE (11), Edge, and Opera Mini. Other major browsers now all support `overflow-wrap` ([source](http://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap)). This property can be set to:

- `normal` - breaks only between words
- `break-word` - may break words in the middle if necessary

> In contrast to `word-break`, `overflow-wrap` will only create a break if an entire word cannot be placed on its own line without overflowing.

There is another property called `word-break` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)) which control how words are broken. Accepted values:

- `normal` - default
- `break-all` - break between **any two characters** of a word
- `keep-all` - identical to `normal` for non-CJK (Chinese/Japanese/Korean) text

> In contrast to `overflow-wrap`, `word-break` will create a break at the exact place where text would otherwise overflow its container (even if putting an entire word on its own line would negate the need for a break).

So it would seem there are two options to get properly wrapped text:

- `overflow-wrap: break-word`
- `word-break: break-all`

Here's a comparison of the two, along with a no-wrapping example:

```css
p {
  background-color: #009AC7;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 250px;
}

.wrap1 {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.wrap2 {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
No wrapping:
<p><b>pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis</b> refers to a lung disease contracted from the inhalation of very fine silica particles, specifically from a volcano;</p>

<code>word-wrap: normal</code> and <code>word-break: normal</code>
<p class="wrap1"><b>pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis</b> refers to a lung disease contracted from the inhalation of very fine silica particles, specifically from a volcano;</p>

<code>word-wrap: normal</code> and <code>word-break: break-all</code>
<p class="wrap2"><b>pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis</b> refers to a lung disease contracted from the inhalation of very fine silica particles, specifically from a volcano;</p>
```

Can you see the problem? If you are using the latest Chrome, for example, the word breaks are placed at arbitrary points. There is nothing preventing your browser from breaking `from` into `f-rom` because it would need to understand the hyphenation rules for the particular language.

Fortunately, there is `hyphens` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens)) which should solve your problem. The value `auto` should allow the browser to decide when to hyphenate.

> Hyphenation rules are language-specific. In HTML, the language is determined by the `lang` attribute, and browsers will hyphenate only if this attribute is present and if an appropriate hyphenation dictionary is available. In XML, the `xml:lang` attribute must be used.
>
> Note: The rules defining how hyphenation is performed are not explicitly defined by the specification, so the exact hyphenation may vary from browser to browser.

Let's see it in action:

```css
p {
  background-color: #009AC7;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<code>hyphens: auto</code>
<p lang="en-US"><b>pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis</b> refers to a lung disease contracted from the inhalation of very fine silica particles, specifically from a volcano;</p>
```

In the latest Chrome on Mac this produced a nice result (although the gaps in the text are not very pleasant to look at), conforming to the English hyphenation rules.

Unfortunately, support for this property is a little spotty. Chrome supports this only on Mac and Android. Safari, IE, and Edge require vendor prefixes ([source](http://caniuse.com/#search=hyphens)). If this is good enough for you, use `hyphens`. If not, consider using an alternative solution, such as a JavaScript automatic hyphenator, e.g. [Hyphenator](https://github.com/mnater/Hyphenator). Your last resort would be to use a hyphenation engine to parse your text and find all word-break points, then insert them into your as HTML soft hyphens – `&shy;` – in combination with `hyphens: manual`.

Comment: So in short, the answer is no?

Comment: @thephpdev Yeah I would say for now CSS is not capable of this. Not to mention if you have a website in a non-English language then it is virtually hopeless. Javascript solutions are customisable (you just need to find the hyphenation rules for that language). The fallback is quite graceful, and people won't even notice, since most websites don't do text justification.

Comment: Aurel Bily, in my specific use case, I need this to work cross-browser. Going to be looking into libraries to do this. It's funny, at face value it seems like such a simple thing that should have been fully implemented in browsers for years, and then you realise the subtleties of language forbids that. Although in my case, simply forcing strings of characters that won't fit in one line to wrap would suffice. But I need that to work on at least IE9. Damn, corporate systems are so far behind.

Comment: @thephpdev Having to support legacy systems is a pain for sure. But yes, wordwrapping is not super trivial – professional typesetting tools (Indesign, Quark, Latex) have been evolving for a good couple of decades to get to a point where the paragraphs are nicely justified, without hyphen-ladders, without orphan lines, while respecting syllables as well as not splitting between conjunctions, etc, etc. Why do you absolutely need to wrap? Long "strings of characters"?

Comment: It's for a system whereby standardized document templates can be added, with image libraries of approved imagery, and validation rules on all fields throughout the document. However, we were having some users enter ridiculously long URLs and email addresses into spaces where they could not fit onto one line. And it doesn't look good from the user's perspective if it starts poking out of it's container. And where this system generates PDFs for print, we can't just replace it with clickable links for an interactive PDF.